# How to make a vertical reverse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I am trying to is that when the page loads, the scroll on a div shows me the content of the bottom. The perfect example of this is Skype chat or Facebook messenger. you type your message at the bottom, and the message appears at the bottom. If you have more messages, all these go on top. 
The latest massage will always be at the bottom.
The thing is if you have several messages you have to scroll, and the scroll works from bottom to top.

So far I have the following code:

```
$('#list-messages-sent').scrollTop($('#list-messages-sent')[0].scrollHeight);
```

I even added the window.onload:

```
window.onload($('#list-messages-sent').scrollTop($('#list-messages-sent')[0].scrollHeight));
```

But I can't seem to make it work. My scroll always appears at the top

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sY2Jj/)

Comment: if you `console.log()` the `$('#list-messages-sent')[0].scrollHeight` do you get the expected height? If not you might want to try running the code within a `$(window).load(function() {...});`

Comment: I just tested `$('#list-messages-sent').scrollTop($('#list-messages-sent')[0].scrollHeight);` and scrolls down. Tho if I need this to work onload cause it's a chat, it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by onload - when the chat box opens or when the page finishes loading?

Comment: when the chat box opens

Comment: So run the script after the chat box is opened/clicked. Also can you make a `jsfiddle` example?

Comment: @W.D. here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sY2Jj/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the solution! 
So after the div, I just add the js code. So after the div finishes loading, the js script will execute.

Here is what I did

```
<div id="list-messages-sent">
   <?php foreach ($conversation->getMessages() as $message) { ?>
       <div class="message-item">
        ...
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>

<script>
   $('#list-messages-sent').scrollTop($('#list-messages-sent')[0].scrollHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: @BenWest there you go :)